# Layout collapsed in Electron using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am building a Electron app of which layout would be like this:

---

### |    header bar     |

### |col 1| col 2| col 3|

### |    bottom bar     |

There would be 3 columns in the main view between the fixed top and bottom bar while the 3 columns are y-scrollable and each of them has a separate html embedded.

This is the html and SCSS code of my layout but all the columns stick to the top and hidden by the header bar and the bottom bar didn't even show up.
Any idea to fix this? Thanks!

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="top-bar" class="row h-15">
    app title
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="main-screen" class="row">
            <div id="main-col-1" class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-1" type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 1</button>
            </div>
            <div id="main-col-2” class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-2” type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 2</button>
            </div>
            <div id="main-col-3” class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-3” type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 3</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-bar" class="row h-20 text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
    </div>
</body>
```

SCSS

```
html {
}

body {
    min-width: map-get($base, width);
    background-color: map-get($base, background);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#main-screen{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.main-col{
    padding: 0em;
    height: 100%;
    color: #3d02bd;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#main-col-1{
    background-color: #e25bff;
}

#main-col-2{
    background-color: #ddb1ff;
}

#main-col-3{
    background-color: #fbefff;
}

.btn-img{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:#3d02bd;
}

#top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #2a095f;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }

#bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #3d02bd;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This code

also change `” to "`

```css
html {
}

body {
    min-width: map-get($base, width);
    background-color: map-get($base, background);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#main-screen{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.main-col{
    padding: 0em;
    height: 100%;
    color: #3d02bd;
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#main-col-1{
    background-color: #e25bff;
}

#main-col-2{
    background-color: #ddb1ff;
}

#main-col-3{
    background-color: #fbefff;
}

.btn-img{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:#3d02bd;
}

#top-bar {

    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #2a095f;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-bottom:15px;
  }

#bottom-bar {
 

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #3d02bd;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-top:15px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="top-bar" class="row h-15">
    app title
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="main-screen" class="row">
            <div id="main-col-1" class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-1" type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 1</button>
            </div>
            <div id="main-col-2" class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-2" type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 2</button>
            </div>
            <div id="main-col-3" class="col-4 main-col">
                <button id="btn-img-3" type="button" class="btn btn-img btn-lg">btn 3</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-bar" class="row h-20 text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">bottom bar
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It doesn't collapse any more but still, the content doesn't fill the whole screen. Especially for the columns in the middle, how can I make fill the space between the top and bottom bar but the embedded page of the 3 columns still can be scrolled vertically?